# New type of module related error appear since downgrading dependency

Tags: react-native, module, frontend, package.json

Hey I have recently downgraded "react-native-tab-view": "^2.2.0 " to "^1.3.2", and it has been working fine until I closed my simulator and terminal. After re-running it this error below appeared and no matter what changes are made to the code it stays. Can anyone please help

I tried rechanging versions top previous ones and changing back my code structure to previous ones I am sure was working just in case.but no result

```
Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(Unable to resolve module `_wrapObjectFreezeAndFriends` from `/Users/camillebasbous/Project/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/polyfillES6Collections.js`: Module `_wrapObjectFreezeAndFriends` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`. (null))

__38-[RCTCxxBridge loadSource:onProgress:]_block_invoke.228
    RCTCxxBridge.mm:414
___ZL36attemptAsynchronousLoadOfBundleAtURLP5NSURLU13block_pointerFvP18RCTLoadingProgressEU13block_pointerFvP7NSErrorP9RCTSourceE_block_invoke.118
__80-[RCTMultipartDataTask URLSession:streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:]_block_invoke
-[RCTMultipartStreamReader emitChunk:headers:callback:done:]
-[RCTMultipartStreamReader readAllPartsWithCompletionCallback:progressCallback:]
-[RCTMultipartDataTask URLSession:streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:]
__88-[NSURLSession delegate_streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:completionHandler:]_block_invoke
__NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
-[NSBlockOperation main]
-[__NSOperationInternal _start:]
__NSOQSchedule_f
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_continuation_pop
_dispatch_async_redirect_invoke
_dispatch_root_queue_drain
_dispatch_worker_thread2
_pthread_wqthread
start_wqthread
```

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue after installing react-native-maps. Any solution to this?

Comment: Did you try `npm start -- --reset-cache`? We just had this problem and the above fixed it for us. I don't understand the problem or why this might have solved it, but it worked for us!

Comment: Hey it worked with a slow start but worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Don't know why people answer in comments.**

Following solution worked for me.

> npm start -- --reset-cache